# Akka: UntypedActor or Actor?

Tags: akka

It seems there are two base classes in akka: `UntypedActor` and `Actor`. Some documentation extends former, some documentation extends latter. Documentation for both doesn't specify a difference between two. Which one should I use? What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UntypedActor` is the Java API, `Actor` is the Scala API

Comment: TypedActors has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: It looks like I misread the question and thus deleted my answer.  According to the docs I believe this answer is correct.  Because `receive` is a partial function on the Scala `akka.actor.Actor` trait it won't work in a Java application so a separate Java analog to Scala's `akka.actor.Actor` had to be created and that is `UntypedActor`.  You use `UntypedActor` if you are developing a Java Akka application and `Actor` if you are developing a Scala Akka application.